# How do I can see my image in main activity

Tags: android

please see the following code.When I run it, I receive errors.my program is simple and I deleted "activity_main" that it creates during the construction of the new project.

because I want see my image in the main activity of my program..but I receive errors.

```
package com.examplee.dd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSaved){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceSaved);
setContentView(R.drawable.Home);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this "setContentView" always need "int layoutResID" as parameter. So you can't pass "drawable" id in it. Try imageView in your activity and set that activity in "setContentView".

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.home)
```

**OR**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Depending upon your setup of Layout resource.

You **can't set your layout from a drawable resources**. *setContentView()* has to be set from a Layout resource. I guess home is your Layout resource (home.xml). If you don not have home.xml, you have to create one.

Answer (score 0):

`activity_main.xml` is important for you project because it is the **Layout for your app**

Layout instructs android how to display your app

So just put your image inside that layout and display

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a layout file to get your image to show because of the way Android handles Views. So you will have to create a new layout resource file, and use an `ImageView` to show the `drawable`.

An example would be:

```
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```